# Comparing String to String Not Working when the String came from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android

I'm retrieving string data from my sqlitedatabase and compare in to my local variable. But its not working. It goes like this codes below.

```
String hole1 = " ";
Cursor cc = save.rawQuery("Select *from " +data + " where Mobile = '"+ number +"'", null);
cc.moveToFirst();
hole1 = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("Hole1"));
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(  
                    this,  
                    R.layout.spinnerlayout,  
                    new String[] { hole1,"1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8","9" });  adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.soloscorehole1front9)).setAdapter(adapter1);

if( ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.soloscorehole1front9)).getSelectedItem().toString() == hole1){
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"True!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Can anyone point what is wrong with this simple codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `==` to compare strings. Use `string1.equals(string2)` instead. Using `==` compares if the reference to each string is equal whereas `.equals()` compares the values of the strings

Answer (score 2):

String comp like this would be better

```
().getSelectedItem().toString().equals(hole);
```