# validation for empty edit text field is not working

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, textview

I have two `TextView`, two `EditText` and two `Buttons`. I want to set a `DialogBox` or `Toast` when the button is clicked without entering any values in the textview. I have two stings, `s` and `s1`. If `s` and `s1` or either `s` or `s1` is not entered in the edittext, I must get a toast. I wrote a code for toast but it's not working fine!
Can you help me with this?

This is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView name1;
TextView name2;
Button click;
Button samegender;
EditText boyname;
EditText girlname;

ImageView imgview;
AnimationDrawable frameanimation;
Bitmap bmp;

String bread;
String cheese;
char sauce;
MediaPlayer song;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //fullscreen
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().  setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN ,                                           WindowManager LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname1);

    name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname2);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btclick);
samegender=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btsamegender);
samegender.setOnClickListener(this);
    boyname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etboyname);
    boyname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    girlname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etgirlname);
    girlname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
          imgview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageanim);
     imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myanim);
     frameanimation=(AnimationDrawable) imgview.getBackground();
        frameanimation.start();

    click.setOnClickListener(this);
      }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btclick:

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        int i,
        j = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int totlen;
        String flames;
        int[] newarr = new int[20];
        int[] newarr1 = new int[20];

        System.out.println("enter name");

        String s = boyname.getText().toString();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);

        char namearr[] = s.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("enter name");
        String s1 = girlname.getText().toString();
                //code for toast//
                 //if s nd s1 is empty then execute this else executee the rest//
        if((s==" ") && (s1==" "))
        {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"cnt b empty" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).  show();                                              
        }
        else
        {

        StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(s1);
        System.out.println("the string1=" + s);
        System.out.println("the string2=" + s1);

        char namearr1[] = s1.toCharArray();
        try {

            for (i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {

                for (j = 0, d = 0; j < sb1.length(); j++) {

            if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        System.out.println("the buff=" + sb);

        sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
        System.out.println("the buff=" + sb1);
            i = 0;
            break;

                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        sb.length();
        System.out.println("string length=" + sb.length());
        sb1.length();
        System.out.println("string length=" + sb1.length());
        int len = sb.length() + sb1.length();
        totlen = len - 1;
        System.out.println("string length=" + totlen);
        String str = "flames";
        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(str);
        int index = 0;

        str.length();
        int length = str.length();
        System.out.println("the length of flames is=" + str.length());
        while (index < length) {
            char letter = str.charAt(index);
            System.out.println(letter);
            index = index + 1;

        }

        System.out.println(sb2.length());

        int m = 0,
        n = 0;
        for (m = 0;;) {

            if (n == totlen) {
                sb2.deleteCharAt(m);

                System.out.println(sb2 + " m:" + m + " n:" + n);
                System.out.println(sb2);

                n = 0;
                m--;

            } else {
                n++;
            }

            if (m == sb2.length() - 1) {
                m = 0;
            } else {
                m++;
            }

            if (sb2.length() == 1) {
                break;
            }

        }

        char res = sb2.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("the final char is=" + res);

        String bread = boyname.getText().toString();
        String cheese = girlname.getText().toString();

        char sauce = res;

        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("name1", bread);
        basket.putString("name2", cheese);
        basket.putChar("ans", sauce);
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        a.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(a);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing String to String Not Working when the String came from SQLiteDatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250791/comparing-string-to-string-not-working-when-the-string-came-from-sqlitedatabase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your validation to this :

```
if((s.equals("")) && (s1.equals("")))
    {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"cnt b empty" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                              
    }
```

Or you can check like this:

```
if((s.length() == 0) && (s1.length() == 0))
    {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"cnt b empty" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).  show();                                              
    }
```

Tried your code and validation is working :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView name1;
TextView name2;
Button click;
Button samegender;
EditText boyname;
EditText girlname;

ImageView imgview;
Bitmap bmp;

String bread;
String cheese;
char sauce;
MediaPlayer song;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // getWindow(). setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    // ,WindowManager LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname1);

    name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname2);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btclick);
    samegender = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btsamegender);
    samegender.setOnClickListener(this);
    boyname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etboyname);
    boyname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    girlname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etgirlname);
    girlname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageanim);
    frameanimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgview.getBackground();
    frameanimation.start();

    click.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btclick:

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        int i,
        j = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int totlen;
        String flames;
        int[] newarr = new int[20];
        int[] newarr1 = new int[20];

        System.out.println("enter name");

        String s = boyname.getText().toString();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);

        char namearr[] = s.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("enter name");
        String s1 = girlname.getText().toString();
        // code for toast//
        // if s nd s1 is empty then execute this else executee the rest//
        if ((s.equals("")) || (s1.equals(""))) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "cnt b empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(s1);
            System.out.println("the string1=" + s);
            System.out.println("the string2=" + s1);

            char namearr1[] = s1.toCharArray();
            try {

                for (i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {

                    for (j = 0, d = 0; j < sb1.length(); j++) {

                        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb1.charAt(j)) {
                            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                            System.out.println("the buff=" + sb);

                            sb1.deleteCharAt(j);
                            System.out.println("the buff=" + sb1);
                            i = 0;
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            sb.length();
            System.out.println("string length=" + sb.length());
            sb1.length();
            System.out.println("string length=" + sb1.length());
            int len = sb.length() + sb1.length();
            totlen = len - 1;
            System.out.println("string length=" + totlen);
            String str = "flames";
            StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(str);
            int index = 0;

            str.length();
            int length = str.length();
            System.out.println("the length of flames is=" + str.length());
            while (index < length) {
                char letter = str.charAt(index);
                System.out.println(letter);
                index = index + 1;

            }

            System.out.println(sb2.length());

            int m = 0, n = 0;
            for (m = 0;;) {

                if (n == totlen) {
                    sb2.deleteCharAt(m);

                    System.out.println(sb2 + " m:" + m + " n:" + n);
                    System.out.println(sb2);

                    n = 0;
                    m--;

                } else {
                    n++;
                }

                if (m == sb2.length() - 1) {
                    m = 0;
                } else {
                    m++;
                }

                if (sb2.length() == 1) {
                    break;
                }

            }

            char res = sb2.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("the final char is=" + res);

            String bread = boyname.getText().toString();
            String cheese = girlname.getText().toString();

            char sauce = res;

            Bundle basket = new Bundle();
            basket.putString("name1", bread);
            basket.putString("name2", cheese);
            basket.putChar("ans", sauce);
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            a.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(a);
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Iam not getting toast!! Its taking to the next activity

Comment: just change the && condition to ||

Comment: But iam getting error when i use "equals". Iam getting error like change equals to object>when i change that to object stil eror persists in " " this @Arshdeep

Comment: your requirement says you need to use || not &&.

Comment: @anusha Plz check the edit, i have tried your code and validations are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (s.isEmpty() || s1.isEmpty())` to check if your strings are empty. `==` and `.equals` will not work with string comparison because they are comparing the objects and not solely the contents. To check if two strings are equal, you can use `firstString.compareTo(anotherString) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Trim your edittext value then compare

```
 if((("").equals(s.trim())) && (("").equals(s1.trim())))
 {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"cnt b empty" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                              
 }
```